# Extract optimal solution in list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary-comprehension

I have a problem which is to find the location and the plant which offer the least costly options for different firms. Therefore, the list is given as follows:

```
[[{4: [14.038, 28.423, 43.483, 58.00699999999999]},
  {3: [31.645999999999997, 78.993, 110.59100000000001]},
  {1: [30.967000000000002, 68.55000000000001, 100.32900000000001]}],
 [{4: [27.651999999999997, 59.993, 93.76999999999998, 122.67799999999998]},
  {3: [34.604, 80.786, 116.641]},
  {2: [59.28399999999999, 136.2, 206.18, 277.543, 340.03800000000007]},
  {1: [32.953, 77.665, 123.44800000000001]}],
 [{4: [15.295000000000002, 30.656, 47.892999999999994, 63.731999999999985]},
  {3: [29.290999999999997, 74.506, 110.141]}],
 [{4: [36.424, 67.84299999999999, 99.04999999999998, 134.88299999999998]},
  {3: [39.557, 75.643, 111.09500000000001]}]]
```

For instance, the first firm would be :

```
[{4: [14.038, 28.423, 43.483, 58.00699999999999]},
  {3: [31.645999999999997, 78.993, 110.59100000000001]},
  {1: [30.967000000000002, 68.55000000000001, 100.32900000000001]}]
```

and its least costly option would be: Location 4, at plant 0 and a cost of 14.038.

I would like to be able to find the correct code that would return that specific solution. Furthermore, I would like to know if there is a way to return the second best solution. In the case of the first firm, we would have: Location 4, at plant 1 and a cost of 28.423.

Thanks!

Comment: are the plant values always sorted in ascending order?

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to create a dictionary of multiple entries for each firm, instead of creating a list of dictionaries containing only one entry?

Comment: It was given as an assignment to test my python skills but I have yet to master them. Yes, I have noticed that the farther away they are from the center, the larger the distance is. Nonetheless, I am being asked to solve it through coding, which is indeed quite burdensome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to sort all the costs from each firm, location and plant and take the less costly `k`, where `k` is the number of options for (firm, location, plant) you are looking for:

```py
k = 2
best_k = sorted(
    [(c, firm_id, location_id, plant_id)
     for firm_id, plant_res in enumerate(costs)
     for location_res in plant_res
     for location_id, location_costs in location_res.items()
     for plant_id, c in enumerate(location_costs)
     ]
)[:k]
```

where `costs` is the list in your question.

Here `best_k`:

```sh
[(14.038, 0, 4, 0), (15.295000000000002, 2, 4, 0), (27.651999999999997, 1, 4, 0)]
```

So, the less costly option is 14.038, provided by firm 0 at location 4, plant 0.
The second option is 15.295, provided by firm 2 at location 4, plant 0.
And, in the end, the first option is 27.652 provided by firm 1 at location 4, plant 0.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's simple and very effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
 from operator import itemgetter
 
 temp = [[{4: [14.038, 28.423, 43.483, 58.00699999999999]},
   {3: [31.645999999999997, 78.993, 110.59100000000001]},
   {1: [30.967000000000002, 68.55000000000001, 100.32900000000001]}],
  [{4: [27.651999999999997, 59.993, 93.76999999999998, 122.67799999999998]},
   {3: [34.604, 80.786, 116.641]},
   {2: [59.28399999999999, 136.2, 206.18, 277.543, 340.03800000000007]},
   {1: [32.953, 77.665, 123.44800000000001]}],
  [{4: [15.295000000000002, 30.656, 47.892999999999994, 63.731999999999985]},
   {3: [29.290999999999997, 74.506, 110.141]}],
  [{4: [36.424, 67.84299999999999, 99.04999999999998, 134.88299999999998]},
   {3: [39.557, 75.643, 111.09500000000001]}]]
 
 #returns tuple: (index of lowest value, value)
 def get_lowest_value_in_list(location_arr):
     i, value = min(enumerate(location_arr), key=itemgetter(1))
     return i,value
     
 lowest = False
 for i, firm in enumerate(temp):
     for j,location in enumerate(firm):
         location_id = list(location.keys())[0]
         index, value = get_lowest_value_in_list(  temp[i][j][location_id] )
         
         if lowest:
             current_lowest_value = temp[lowest[0]][lowest[1]][lowest[2]][lowest[3]]
             if current_lowest_value > value:
                 lowest = (i,j,location_id,index)
         else:
             lowest = (i,j,location_id,index)
         
 print(lowest)
 result = temp[lowest[0]][lowest[1]][lowest[2]][lowest[3]]
 print(result)
```

The `lowest` is a tuple that stores the location of the lowest value (firm,location_index,location id,index of lowest value)

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate the answer, but Piecot's answer requires less time and inputs which is also needed when running the code.